# ffmpeg: HLS to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have one m3u8 file with `ts` segments. I am trying to convert a part of it to mp4 using the below command.

```
ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u8 -ss 30 -t 120 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -flags +global_header -y output.mp4
```

I manually calculated where my segments are located and concatenated those to form output.ts. And then converted that to mp4 using the below commands.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.ts; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.ts
ffmpeg -i output.ts -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -flags +global_header -y output.mp4
```

I found that the second approach is taking far lesser time compared to the first one, an order of 10s of seconds. Someone, please let me know whether the comparison makes any sense and why there is so much difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `-ss` incorrectly for the live stream.

`-ss` has to be used along side `-live_start_index 0` before input file option `-i input.m3u8`.

For the live streaming from FFMpeg part, one should use `-f hls -hls_playlist_type event` than `-f segment -segment_list_flags live` for seek to work on live streaming.

As mentioned in the document for [-ss](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options), seek doesn't start exactly at 15th sec. And the duration is also not honoured(< 30secs).

```
ffmpeg -live_start_index 0 -ss 15  -i playlist.m3u8 -t 00:00:30 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -flags +global_header -y input.mp4
```

When used without `-c copy` and with transcoding and `-accurate_seek`, the duration is fine. But the seek position is the same as the one with `-c copy`.